# httpinterceptor in NativeScript not working properly

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using httpinterceptor to intercept http headers with JWT token but not working.

Here is my GET method. Manually adding headers in request is working but with httpinterceptor.

```
loadLoginData() {
        const url = 'http://mywebpage/myurl',
        const tokenInfo = appSettings.getString('TokenInfo');
        request({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenInfo}`, "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        }).then((response: HttpResponse) => {
            const d = response.content.toJSON();
        }, (e) => {
            alert(e);
        });
    }
```

`headers: { Authorization:`Bearer ${tokenInfo}`, "Content-Type": "application/json" },` --> If I add this line, it works well otherwise request goes as anonymous.

httpinterceptors.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as appSettings from "tns-core-modules/application-settings";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class httpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, newRequest: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const tokenInfo = appSettings.getString('TokenInfo');
    if (tokenInfo) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenInfo}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
    }

    return newRequest.handle(request);
  }
}
```

shared.moduele.ts

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from 'nativescript-angular/common';
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from 'nativescript-angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { httpInterceptor } from '../interceptor/httpInterceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    NativeScriptHttpModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule
  ],
  exports: [
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    NativeScriptHttpModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: httpInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

What did I do mistake here?

Comment: May I know where the `request` method is defined in `loadLoginData`?

Comment: I did not get you. Could you elaborate more ?

Comment: Is your intercept method getting called?

Comment: providers: [ { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: httpInterceptor, multi: true } ], is placed

Comment: You are calling a method named request inside loadLoginData where it's defined, is it the method from NativeScript core modules.

Comment: It is a the HTTP module provides a functionality, which allows submitting GET and POST requests for both platforms (iOS and Android). as per https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up {N} Core and Angular. The `"tns-core-modules/http"` module is generally used on {N} Core applications with JavaScript / TypeScript.

For Angular you should refer the [HttpClientModule](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ng-framework-modules/http), the interceptors will listen and intercept calls made only via to Angular's `HttpClient` class.